# Prove that the metric spaces $(X,d)$ and $(X,d(x,y)^{1/3})$ are homemorphic.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, where $d$ is the standard metric. Define a new metric $d': \mathbb{R} 
\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow$ by
$$ d'(x,y) = d(x,y)^{1/3}. $$
Prove that $(X,d)$ and $(X,d')$ are homemorphic.

I'm very unsure on how to prove this, but I am assuming that the idea is to show that one can construct a function $f: (X,d) \rightarrow (X,d')$ that is continuous, bijective and has a continuous inverse. But without a specific choice for $f$, I do not know how to prove this. If I am on the right track, how does one pick an appropriate $f$? (This is not homework)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Where did you get this problem from?

Comment: Have you tried taking the identity function? This is clearly bijective, so you only need to prove it is bicontinuous.

Comment: **HINT**: What happens if you take $d' = \phi\circ d$ for any homeomorphism $\phi$ of $\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$?

Comment: @AnotherUser The problem is given as a practice question in the Topology course which I am enrolled in.

Comment: @A.ThomasYerger That is what I did initially, and proving that is was a homeomorphism was quite straightforward from there. Although it feels a bit odd to me to have the identity as a mapping between two topologies that do not have the exact same elements. Does that make sense?

Comment: You're not defining the identity between two topologies. You're defining the identity function $f: X \to X$ such that $f(x) = x$. There is a difference here.

Comment: @MordeusMorgenstern I see, thank you! I think my misunderstanding is arising from the fact that I am thinking of $x$ as an element of the topology $\mathcal{T}$ (generated by $d$) which is being mapped to another element in the topology $\mathcal{T}'$ (generated by $d'$) by $f$, instead of seeing $f$ as a mapping between the sets $X$ and $X'$, where $X = X'$ in our case. And obviously one can always define an identity mapping between two identical sets. Am I correct?

Comment: Yea that's correct. One of the answers below deals with your question by showing that both the topologies are the same. Even if you were to define a function $f: \mathcal{T} \to \mathcal{T}'$ with $f(A) = A$, this would certainly be the identity mapping between both sets but it wouldn't make sense to ask whether $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @MordeusMorgenstern Think I got it, thanks. Thank you for your answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take $f(x)=x$ (that is, $f$ is the identity function).

If $x_0\in X$, and $\varepsilon>0$, if you take $\delta=\sqrt[3]\varepsilon$, then\begin{align}d'(x,x_0)<\delta&\iff\sqrt[3]{d(x,y)}<\sqrt[3]\varepsilon\\&\iff d(x,y)<\varepsilon.\end{align}This proves that $f$ is continuous as a map from $(X,d')$ onto $(X,d)$. Can you do it in the other direction?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This is actually how I tried to solve it initially, but for reasons I mentioned in the above comments thought it would be invalid to define an identity between the metric spaces. However, here is my proof that $f: (X,d) \rightarrow (X,d')$ is continuous: Show that for each $a \in X$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ s.t $d'(f(x),f(a)) < \epsilon$ whenever $d(x,a) < \delta$. $d'(f(x),f(a)) = d'(x,a) = |x-a|^{1/3} < \epsilon$. Find $\delta$ now such that $d(x,a) = |x-a| < \delta$. We see $\delta = \epsilon^3$ does the trick. Correct?

Comment: Since you did not say what $f$ is, I have no way of knowing whether it is right or wrong.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention: f: $(X,d) \rightarrow (X,d')$, $f(x) = x$

Comment: Yes, $\delta=\varepsilon^3$ does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another simple way to view it: actually, the topologies $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}'$ induced in $X$ by $d$ and $d'$, respectively, are actually the same topology.

Indeed, $U$ is open in $\mathcal{T}$ $\iff$ for all $x\in U$ there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\mathrm{B}_d(x,\varepsilon)=\mathrm{B}_{d'}(x,\varepsilon^{1/3})\subset U$ (where $\mathrm{B}_d$ and $\mathrm{B}_{d'}$ denote open balls for the metrics $d$ and $d'$, respectively) $\iff$ $U$ is open in $\mathcal{T}'$.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a really nice way to solve the problem by appealing to the sequential definition of continuity. Let $f: (X,d) \to (X,d')$ be the identity mapping. Let $x_0 \in X$ be a fixed point and let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence that converges to $x_0$ in the metric $d$. Then:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} d(a_n,x_0) = 0$$
But using the continuity of the cube root function, we have that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (d(f(a_n),f(x_0)))^{\frac{1}{3}} = (\lim_{n \to \infty} d(a_n,x_0))^{\frac{1}{3}} = 0$$
Now, we want to prove continuity of the inverse of $f$. Once again, let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $X$ that converges to $x_0$ in the metric $d'$. So:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} d'(a_n,x_0) = 0$$
But now, we use the continuity of the cubic $x \mapsto x^3$ to conclude that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} d(f(a_n),f(x_0)) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (d'(a_n,x_0))^3 =(\lim_{n \to \infty} d'(a_n,x_0))^3 = 0$$
Hence, $f$ is a homeomorphism and you're done.